# Se muestra información al enviar formulario PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, formularios, phpmailer

Tengo un incoveniente es que me esta mostrando la informacion de la configuracion de envio de PHPMailer, y esto no deberia pasar. Tengo todo configurado desde mi hosting y funciona perfectamente pero no quiero lo que me esta sucediendo cuando envio el formulario me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He investigado pero no encuentro nada sobre esto, parece que solo me sucede a mi.

Formulario html `index.html`

```
<section id="sp-contacto"><div class="row"><div id="sp-contacto" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="sp-column "><div class="sp-module "><div class="sp-module-content">
<div class="rsform">
    <form method="post"  id="userForm" class="formResponsive" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="enviarCorreo.php" style="padding: 20px !importat;"><div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">CONTACTO</h2>
<div class="row">
<div id="rsform_error_6" style="display: none;"><p class="formRed">Please complete all required fields!</p></div>
<!-- Do not remove this ID, it is used to identify the page so that the pagination script can work correctly -->
    <fieldset class="formHorizontal formContainer" id="rsform_6_page_0">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-name">
                <div class="formControls">
                <div class="formBody"><input type="text" value="" size="20"  name="nombre" id="Name" placeholder="Nombre" class="rsform-input-box"/><span class="formValidation"><span id="component33" class="formNoError">Ingrese su nombre</span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-telefono">
                <div class="formControls">
                <div class="formBody"><input type="text" value="" size="20"  name="telefono" id="Telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" class="rsform-input-box"/><span class="formValidation"><span id="component35" class="formNoError">Por favor ingrese un numero de teléfono</span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-email">
                <div class="formControls">
                <div class="formBody"><input type="text" value="" size="20"  name="email" id="Email" placeholder="E-mail" class="rsform-input-box"/><span class="formValidation"><span id="component34" class="formNoError">Por favor ingrese su correo electrónico</span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-company">
                <div class="formControls">
                <div class="formBody"><input type="text" value="" size="20"  name="company" id="company" placeholder="Empresa" class="rsform-input-box"/><span class="formValidation"><span id="component38" class="formNoError">Entrada inválida</span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-message">
            <div class="formControls">
            <div class="formBody"><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="mensaje" id="Message" placeholder="Mensaje" class="rsform-text-box"></textarea><span class="formValidation"><span id="component36" class="formNoError">Por favor escriba un mensaje</span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-send">
                <div class="formControls">
                <div class="formBody"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit" id="Send"  class="rsform-submit-button" /><span class="formValidation"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</div><input type="hidden" name="form[formId]" value="6"/></form><script type="text/javascript">var rsfp_ajax_root = ''</script><script type="text/javascript">rsfp_addEvent(window, 'load', function(){var form = rsfp_getForm(6); form.onsubmit = ajaxValidation;});</script></div></div></div></div></div></div></section><section id="sp-main-body"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div id="sp-component" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="sp-column "><div id="system-message-container">
    </div>
<div class="blog-featured" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
<div class="page-header">
</div>
```

Archivo que procesa el envio de correo `enviarCorreo.php`

```
<?php
require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
require("PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");

$nombre = $email = $telefono = $mensaje = $company = NULL;

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];

 $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
 $mail->Host = "mail.host.com";
 $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
 $mail->Username = "user@correo.com";
 $mail->Password = "password;
 $mail->SetFrom("correoejemplo@de.com", 'prueba');
 $mail->AddAddress("correo@destino.com");
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
 $mail->Subject = 'Formulario de contacto';
 $mail->Body    =  'Nombre:' .$name .'<br>' .
                   'Telefono:' .$telefono .'<br>' .
                   'Empresa:' .$company .'<br>' .
                   'Mensaje:' .$mensaje;
 
  //Comprobamos el envio.
     if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "<script>alert('Controla la informacion ingresada, el mensaje NO se ha enviado');
 window.location='https://misitioweb.com/#sp-contacto'

 
 </script>";
 } else {
 echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando');
                    window.location='https://misitioweb.com/'
                  </script>";
 }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hola, tienes activado el debug, intenta esto $mail->SMTPDebug = false; actualmente lo tienes en 1, que es para mostrar errores y mensajes.

Comment: @Krengifo que novato soy, gracias.